# Regularity of the Robin function

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, green-function

I consider an analytic bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^3$ and an the operator $L_a=-\Delta +a$ where $a$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$. I assume the operator to be coercive, in particular there exists a Green function $G_a :\Omega\times \Omega \setminus D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ symmetric such that
$$ L_a G_a(x,y)= \delta_y \text{ on } \Omega,$$
and
$$G_a(x,y)=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega,$$
where $D=\{ (x,x) \,\vert\, x \in \Omega \}$.
I can write
$$G_a(x,y)= \frac{c}{\vert x-y\vert} + H_a(x,y),$$
where $H_a \in L^\infty( \Omega \times \Omega, \mathbb R)$. We use to call $\rho_a(x)= H_a(x,x)$ the Robin function.

**My question is, if $a$ analytic, is $\rho_a$ analytic ?**

First it has to be noticed, it is false for $H_a$, since it is not hard to prove that locally $H(x,y)=d +d'\vert x-y\vert +...$.

But it is true for $\rho_a$ when $a$ is constant. The idea is quite simple, we first build a solution $S_a$ of
$$ L_a S_a =-\frac{ac}{\vert x-y\vert}$$
by setting
$$S_0(x,y)=\frac{ac \vert x-y\vert}{2}$$ which solves
$$ -\Delta S_ 0 =-\frac{ac}{\vert x-y\vert}$$
then
$$ -\Delta S_{n+1}= -ac S_n$$
it is not hard to show that $S_a =\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n$ converges and solves the desired equations. Moreover $S_a(x,y)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \vert x-y \vert^{1+2n}$ is such that $S_a(x,y)$ is symmetric and $S_a(x,x)=0$.
Hence $F_a = H_a -S_a$ solves
$$L_a F_a =0$$
Hence it is analytic in $x$ in the interior( we just need $a$ analytic here) and symmetric in $x$ and $y$( because $H_a$ and $S_a$ are), hence $\rho_a(x)=F_a(x,x)$ is analytic.

The argument work well, since when $a$ is constant, we can almost explicitly solves

$$ L_aS_a =-\frac{ac}{\vert x-y\vert}$$

What we only need in the general case is to find **any symmetric solution in $x$ and $y$ which vanishes on the diagonal**. The end of the proof should work the same.

Despite the problem of the regularity of the Robin function seems quite natural, I found only few references... any idea or reference is welcome.

Comment: when you try with the very same S_0, in the non constant case, why is the extra term bad?

Comment: in this case $a(x)$ depends on $x$ so $S_0$ is no more a solution, moreover it is not symmetric in $x$ and $y$.